# OnPress that redirect to other page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to develop an application to learn react native and I am stuck with the login/register. 
I have a register.js that works properly, as I have tested it before, and I wanted to add a resiter button to redirect to the register page from the login one.

From the UserLogin.js, the button is this one:

```
<TouchableOpacity
         onPress={() => navigate('Register')}
        style={{width:200,padding:10,backgroundColor:'pink',alignItems:'center'}}>
        <Text style={{color:'black'}}>Register</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

UserLogin.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,TouchableOpacity,TextInput,Button,Keyboard
} from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';



class UserLogin extends  React.Component  {

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={
            userEmail:'',
            userPassword:''
        }
    }

    login = () =>{
        const {userEmail,userPassword} = this.state;
        let reg = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/ ;
        if(userEmail==""){
            //alert("Please enter Email address");
          this.setState({email:'Please enter Email address'})

        }

        else if(reg.test(userEmail) === false)
        {
        //alert("Email is Not Correct");
        this.setState({email:'Email is Not Correct'})
        return false;
          }

        else if(userPassword==""){
        this.setState({email:'Please enter password'})
        }
        else{

        fetch('http://192.168.1.47/login.php',{
            method:'post',
            header:{
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-type': 'application/json'
            },
            body:JSON.stringify({
                // we will pass our input data to server
                email: userEmail,
                password: userPassword
            })

        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
         .then((responseJson)=>{
             if(responseJson == "ok"){
                 // redirect to profile page
                 alert("Successfully Login");
                 //this.props.navigation.navigate("Profile");
             }else{
                 alert("Wrong Login Details");
             }
         })
         .catch((error)=>{
         console.error(error);
         });
        }


        Keyboard.dismiss();
    }

  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (        
    <View style={styles.container}>    
    <Text style={{padding:10,margin:10,color:'red'}}>{this.state.email}</Text>

    <TextInput
    placeholder="Enter Email"
    style={{width:200, margin:10}}
    onChangeText={userEmail => this.setState({userEmail})}
    />

    <TextInput
    placeholder="Enter Password"
    style={{width:200, margin:10}}
    onChangeText={userPassword => this.setState({userPassword})}

    />


    <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={this.login}
        style={{width:200,padding:10,backgroundColor:'magenta',alignItems:'center'}}>
        <Text style={{color:'white'}}>Login</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>

    <TouchableOpacity
         onPress={() => navigate('Register')}
        style={{width:200,padding:10,backgroundColor:'pink',alignItems:'center'}}>
        <Text style={{color:'black'}}>Register</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>


     </View>

   );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },

});
export default UserLogin
AppRegistry.registerComponent('login', () => login);
```

register.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, ActivityIndicator, Platform } from 'react-native';

class Register extends React.Component
{
    constructor()
    {
        super();

        this.state = { first_name: '', last_name: '', email: '', password: '', loading: false, disabled: false }
    }

    saveData = () =>
    {
        this.setState({ loading: true, disabled: true }, () =>
        {
            fetch('http://192.168.1.47/user_registration.php',
            {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: 
                {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(
                {
                    first_name: this.state.first_name,
                    last_name: this.state.last_name,
                    email: this.state.email,
                    password: this.state.password,
                })

            }).then((response) => response.json()).then((responseJson) =>
            {
                //Faire une redirection evrs le profile de l'utilisateur
                alert(responseJson);
                this.setState({ loading: false, disabled: false });
            }).catch((error) =>
            {
                console.error(error);
                this.setState({ loading: false, disabled: false });
            });
        });
    }

    render()
    {
        return(
            <View style = { styles.container }>
                <TextInput underlineColorAndroid = "transparent" placeholder = "Your First Name" style = { styles.textInput } onChangeText = {(text) => this.setState({ first_name: text })}/>

                <TextInput underlineColorAndroid = "transparent" placeholder = "Your Last Name" style = { styles.textInput } onChangeText = {(text) => this.setState({ last_name: text })}/>

                <TextInput underlineColorAndroid = "transparent" placeholder = "Your Email adress" style = { styles.textInput } onChangeText = {(text) => this.setState({ email: text })}/>

                <TextInput underlineColorAndroid = "transparent" placeholder = "Your Password" style = { styles.textInput } onChangeText = {(text) => this.setState({ password: text })}/>

                <TouchableOpacity disabled = { this.state.disabled } activeOpacity = { 0.8 } style = { styles.Btn } onPress = { this.saveData }>
                    <Text style = { styles.btnText }>Sign up</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>

                {
                    (this.state.loading)
                    ?
                        (<ActivityIndicator size = "large" />)
                    :
                        null
                }

            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create(
{
    container:
    {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#eee',
        paddingHorizontal: 25,
        paddingTop: (Platform.OS == 'ios') ? 20 : 0
    },

    textInput:
    {
        height: 40,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: 'grey',
        marginVertical: 5,
        alignSelf: 'stretch',
        padding: 8,
        fontSize: 16
    },

    Btn:
    {
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.6)',
        alignSelf: 'stretch',
        padding: 10,
        marginTop: 10,
        marginBottom: 25
    },

    btnText:
    {
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: 'white',
        fontSize: 16
    }
});

export default Register
```

Navigation.js

```
import Search from '../Components/Search';
import ProductDetail from '../Components/ProductDetail';
//import UserAccount from '../Components/UserAccount';
import UserLogin from '../Components/UserLogin';
//import UserRegistration from '../Components/UserRegistration';
import Transaction from '../Components/Transaction';

import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import React from 'react';
import {  Image , Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';


const SearchStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Rechercher : {
        screen: Search,
        navigationOptions: ({ navigate, navigation }) => ({
            title:'Rechercher',
            headerTitleStyle: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                color: 'white',
                marginLeft:5,
              },
            headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: '#FF6100',
            },
            headerLeft: ( 
                <TouchableOpacity 
                    onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Rechercher')}>
                    <Image
                        style={{
                            width: 35, 
                            height: 35,
                            marginLeft: 25,
                        }}
                        source={require('../Images/logo.jpg')}
                    />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            ),
            headerRight: ( 
                <TouchableOpacity 
                    onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Account')}>
                    <Image
                        style={{
                            width: 35, 
                            height: 35,
                            marginRight: 25,
                        }}
                        source={require('../Images/user.png')}
                    />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            )
        })
    },
    ProductDetail : {
        screen: ProductDetail,
        navigationOptions: ({ navigate, navigation }) => ({
            title:'Détail du produit',
            headerTitleStyle: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                color: 'white',
                marginLeft:5,
            },
            headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: '#FF6100',
            },
            headerLeft: ( 
                <TouchableOpacity 
                    onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Rechercher')}>
                    <Image
                        style={{
                            width: 35, 
                            height: 35,
                            marginLeft: 25,
                        }}
                        source={require('../Images/logo.jpg')}
                    />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            ),
            headerRight: ( 
                <TouchableOpacity 
                    onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Account')}>
                    <Image
                        style={{
                            width: 35, 
                            height: 35,
                            marginRight: 25,
                        }}
                        source={require('../Images/user.png')}
                    />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            )
        })
    },
    Account: {
        //screen: UserRegistration,
        screen: UserLogin,
        navigationOptions: ({ navigate, navigation }) => ({
            title:'Compte utilisateur',
            headerTitleStyle: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                color: 'white',
                marginLeft:5,
              },
            headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: '#FF6100',
            },
            headerLeft: ( 
                <TouchableOpacity 
                    onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Rechercher')}>
                    <Image
                        style={{
                            width: 35, 
                            height: 35,
                            marginLeft: 25,
                        }}
                        source={require('../Images/logo.jpg')}
                    />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            ),
            headerRight: ( 
                <TouchableOpacity 
                    onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Account')}>
                    <Image
                        style={{
                            width: 35, 
                            height: 35,
                            marginRight: 25,
                        }}
                        source={require('../Images/user.png')}
                    />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            )
        })
    },
    Transaction: {
        screen: Transaction,
        navigationOptions: ({ navigate, navigation }) => ({
            title:'Transaction',
            headerTitleStyle: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                color: 'white',
                marginLeft:5,
              },
            headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: '#FF6100',
            },
            headerLeft: ( 
                <TouchableOpacity 
                    onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Rechercher')}>
                    <Image
                        style={{
                            width: 35, 
                            height: 35,
                            marginLeft: 25,
                        }}
                        source={require('../Images/logo.jpg')}
                    />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            ),
            headerRight: ( 
                <TouchableOpacity 
                    onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Account')}>
                    <Image
                        style={{
                            width: 35, 
                            height: 35,
                            marginRight: 25,
                        }}
                        source={require('../Images/user.png')}
                    />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            )
        })
    },
})
export default createAppContainer(SearchStackNavigator)
```

Navigation.js is located on a folder named Navigation. 
The two other files are on the same folder (The components one).

Can someone help  me fixe it ? I don't think it's complicated, but there is something I didn't understand, I think.

Thank you in advance. 
Noémie.

Comment: Where's your stackNavigator, Noemie?

Comment: In a Navigation.js file (Navigation folder), I have edited my question to add it!

Comment: Your `Register`, and `Login` screens have to be listed as routes in your stack-navigation ... so you can get access to `navigation` object to use it for navigation ... and your `stackNavigator` has to be your top-component to render when your app launches

Comment: It works! It was that! Thanks you a lot (from the baguette country ;) )

Comment: Greetings dear! ... Happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Your Register, and Login screens have to be listed as routes in your
>   stack-navigation ... so you can get access to navigation object to use
>   it for navigation – Hend El-Sahli